# tex4ht: limit toc

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht

When I run the following file through `htlatex main html,4`, the first (main) page has a table of contents that is too deeply nested. I only need part,chapter and section in my toc. The section page should have the subsection in it. **How to get rid of the subsection in the first page?**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\part {First part}
\chapter{A chapter}
\blindtext
\section{A section}
\blindtext
\subsection{A subsection}
\blindtext
\section{A section}
\blindtext
\subsection{A subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try with `htlatex main html,3`?

Comment: @egreg when I read your comment, I realized that my question was wrong. I only want to get rid of the subsection, when the level is the part level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me (although it doesn't answer the question directly) is the following in the config file:

```
\TocAt{part,chapter,section}
\TocAt{chapter,section}
```

This limits the listed items of a "part" page to chapter and section and on a "chapter" page to section.

The first page is not affected however, but I got rid of it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Appereance of toc entries can be controlled with `\ConfigureToc`. When its parameters are empty, this toc level will be not print. Try this private config file

```
\Preamble{html}
\ConfigureToc{subsection}{}{}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Save as `pg.cfg` and run `htlatex file "pg,4"`

Comment: That is the appearance only. I need to limit the entries in the part,chapter and section pages.