# No minitoc in chapter pages with TeX4HT

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht

TeX4HT allows to create one HTML page per chapter with `2,next` in the options:

```
htlatex project.tex 'xhtml,2,next,charset=utf-8' ' -cunihtf -utf8 -cvalidate'
```

This, however, creates a minitoc in the head of every chapter:

[image: minitoc in chapter page]

How can I get rid of this minitoc?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44541/tex4ht-limit-toc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @michal.h21's comment, my solution is:

```
\Preamble{html}
\TocAt{chapter}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

in my config file.